# How to create multiple instances of same provider in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I create unique instance of a same provider in a screen so that i can create 10 counters with each count value independent of others. Is there any way to do that using provider? value of other counters shouldnt be incremented if i increment value of one counter. There is (.family) modifier in riverpod to achieve my goal but i dont seem to see any way to do that using provider.

Comment: I just asked a similar question here including an example. I am currently looking into RiverPod, but it looks even more confusing. So I havent found a proper solution yet, have you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042732/flutter-provider-multiple-instances-of-same-object

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way to do something like that easily with Provider.
Provider's author also create a state management/dependency injection package called Riverpod.
Riverpod has a feature called `family`. With family you can create multiple provider instance by differentiating between them with an id.
An id could be a string, number or an immutable object.

```dart
final counterFamily = StateNotifierProvider.family<CounterNotifier, int, int>((ref, id) {
  return CounterNotifier();
});
```

To consume the CounterNotifier inside ConsumerWidget

```dart
final int id;
///

///
ref.watch(counterFamily(id));
```