# Flutter Provider multiple instances of same object

Tags: flutter-provider

The code below (which can be directly copy/pasted in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)) creates 3 tabs based on the list of categories, in this case: `'People', 'Cars', 'Animals'`.

The app does not work properly because if you click the 'Count' button the counter increases on all pages, obviously. The counter should increase for each tab page separately. So I would like to have a separate instance of `Data` per page, but I can't figure out how to do that in Flutter.

I am unable to create an inherited data object per category because, for my real app, I don't know the categories in advance.

Any Ideas?

[image]

**This code can be copy/pasted directly in https://dartpad.dev/**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
        create: (context) => Data(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: _title,
          home: MyHomePage(),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> categories = ['People', 'Cars', 'Animals'];
  List<Tab> getTabs(int tabsCount) {
    List<Tab> tabs = [];
    for (var category in categories) {
      tabs.add(
        Tab(text: category),
      );
    }
    return tabs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tabs = getTabs(4);
    var data = Provider.of<Data>(context);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: tabs,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: tabs.map((Tab tab) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    tab.text!,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  Text(
                    data.counter.toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: data.increment, child: const Text('Count'))
                ],
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  void increment() {
    counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have come up with the following solution, **see the code below which you can run directly in DartPad**: I have moved the `ChangeNotifierProvider` to wrap around the tabpages directly. This way you can have multiple instances of the same type. The tabPage looks up the tree for the Provider and finds the nearest one.

Still, I think the provider pattern isn't very flexible. In the example below the Data provider is disposed each time the tab page moves out of view, and recreated when moved in view. I will test  this tomorrow in my real app.

You can copy/paste the code below directly in dartpad and test it yourself:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<MyExtendedTab> getTabs() {
    List<MyExtendedTab> tabs = [];
    for (var category in Repo.categories) {
      tabs.add(
        MyExtendedTab(category),
      );
    }
    return tabs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tabs = getTabs();
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: tabs,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: //tabPages
                tabs.map((MyExtendedTab tab) {
              // Moved the ChangeNotifierProvider here to directly wrap the tabpage(s) so the tab page will find its corresponding ChangeNotifierProvider when moving op in the widget tree
              // this way we can have multiple provider instances of the same type
              return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
                  // Here the Data object (ChangeNotifier) is instantiated with an id. This id determines which data to retrieve.
                  create: (context) => Data(
                        category: tab.category,
                      ),
                  child: Consumer<Data>(builder: (context, data, child) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${data.category.name} ${data.category.id}',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        Text(
                          data.counter.toString(),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: data.increment,
                            child: const Text('Count'))
                      ],
                    );
                  }));
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Category category;
  Data({required this.category}) {
    print('Data.constructor id:${category.id}');
  }

  int get counter {
    print(
        'Data.get counter id:${category.id}; Repo.counters:${Repo.counters.length}');
    return Repo.counters[category.id];
  }

  void increment() {
    Repo.counters[category.id]++;
    notifyListeners();
    print('counters: ${Repo.counters}');
  }
}

// the mockup repo: this is where the data is 'stored'.
class Repo {
  static List<Category> categories = [
    Category(id: 0, name: 'People'),
    Category(id: 1, name: 'Cars'),
    Category(id: 2, name: 'Animals')
  ];

  // just a list of integers to store the counter values. 1st int is for People, 2nd int for Cars, etc.
  static List<int> counters = [0, 0, 0];
}

class Category {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Category({required this.id, required this.name});
}

// I need the Id in the tab to work with, hence an extendedTab
class MyExtendedTab extends Tab {
  final Category category;
  MyExtendedTab(this.category, {super.key}) : super(text: category.name);
}
```

TL;DR I have also looked at RiverPod, but it only seems to work with simple types? and although the documentation is ample, the provided code examples are vague at best. I ended up writing code like this:

```
onPressed: ref.read(counterProvider(category).notifier).increment,
```

instead of

```
onPressed: data.increment,
```

I prefer the latter...